# Is there a version-specific compilation symbol when SSIS compiles script components?

Tags: ssis, script-component

I have packages that use script components as a data source. Some of them override the `PrimeOutput` method from the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponent` class. In 2008, this method has 3 parameters, but starting in 2012, it now has four parameters.

These packages are currently executing under SSIS 2008, but will soon be moved to SSIS 2014. I need to open these packages up and fix the issue, but I would like to do it ahead of time and still be able to deploy to SSIS 2008, but also have them work under 2014 when the new environment is ready without having to make additional changes when moving between environments.

If I could differentiate between environments at compile time, then I can get around this problem, but that would mean I would need to use preprocessor directives. I know I can define them in the script component's project file, but I'd like this to work in SSIS 2008 and SSIS 2012 without having to make changes to the .dtsx file.

Does anyone know if the various versions of SSIS define version-specific directives when compiling script components?